# TFS 2015 Buikd and Nuget Error

Tags: nuget, tfs-2015

I am trying to automate the TFS build process, so that when a dll gets built, it will go to NuGet Server, using TFS 2015.

I updated the nugget exe on TFS agent (C:\Lucky\agent\agent\Worker\Tools)

Now I am getting an error when publishing to local nugget server. I tried so many option but still getting the error.

I am not sure what is going wrong. Also anyone share good step by step process to automate TFS build process with Nuget?

Error

> Set workingFolder to default:
>   C:\Lucky\agent\tasks\NuGetPublisher\0.1.41 Executing the powershell
>   script: C:\Lucky\agent\tasks\NuGetPublisher\0.1.41\NuGetPublisher.ps1
>   Check/Set nuget path Creating Nuget Arguments Getting credentials for
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.TaskEndpoint
>   Saving to C:\Lucky\agent_work\2\NuGet\newNuGet.config No Pattern
>   found in solution parameter. Found files: 1 File:
>   C:\Lucky\agent_work\2\s\Dev\TestDLL Invoking nuget with push
>   "C:\Lucky\agent_work\2\s\Dev\TestDLL" -s
>   http://localhost/NuGetLocalSvr/ -configFile
>   "C:\Lucky\agent_work\2\NuGet\newNuGet.config" -apiKey VssSessionKey
>   nuget setapikey {XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX} on
>   C:\Lucky\agent_work\2\s\Dev\TestDLL
>   C:\Lucky\agent\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe push
>   "C:\Lucky\agent_work\2\s\Dev\TestDLL" -s
>   http://localhost/NuGetLocalSvr/ -configFile
>   "C:\Lucky\agent_work\2\NuGet\newNuGet.config" -apiKey VssSessionKey
>   nuget setapikey {XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX} Ambiguous option
>   's'. Possible values: Source SymbolSource SymbolApiKey. Unexpected
>   exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not suggest to update the `nuget.exe` separately on your build agent. Even though your `nuget.exe` is using latest version, the task about nuget publish on your build agent is stilling calling the older version. Which maybe the error's root cause.

> **NuGet extensions must be used with the exact version of nuget.exe for which they are designed**. If you use your own nuget.exe, NuGet
>   extensions included on the build agent may not be compatible and the
>   NuGet build tasks will not load them.

You could try to update your build agent.  Right-click on the agent pool that you want to update. Choose **Update All Agents** from the context menu. Detail steps please refer this tutorial-- [Updating Your Team Foundation Build Agents](http://blog.devmatter.com/updating-your-team-foundation-build-agents/)

Another way is manually downloading the latest version of build agent from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases). Install and configure the agent, stop the old agent service, stat the new agent service. After this trigger the build again to see if the error gone.

---

As for a step by step process to automate TFS build process with Nuget, suggest you refer the official tutorial from MSDN: [Use Team Build to restore and publish NuGet packages](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/build/team-build-nuget)

> Include three parts:
>
> - Restore packages at the start of your build
> - Create NuGet packages during your build
> - Publish packages created by your build

Comment: Thanks for your help.